# SQL how to display column values based on conditions being fulfilled in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

You have the table seats, which describes seats in the airplane. It has the following columns:

- seat_no - The unique number of the seat;
- status - The status of the
  seat (0 indicates free, 1 indicates reserved, and 2 indicates
  purchased);
- person_id - The ID of the person who reserved/purchased
  this seat (0 if the corresponding status is 0).

You also have the table requests, which contains the following columns:

- request_id - The unique ID of the request;
- request - The description of the request (1 indicates reserve, 2 indicates purchase);
- seat_no - The number of the seat that the person want to reserve/purchase;
- person_id - The ID of the person who wants to reserve/purchase this seat.

A person can reserve/purchase a free seat and can purchase a seat that they have reserved.

Task is to return the table seats after the given requests have been performed.

Note: requests are applied from the lowest request_id; it's guaranteed that all values of seat_no in the table requests are presented in the table seats.

For the given tables seats

```
seat_no |status|person_id
-------------------------  
1       | 1    |  1   

2       | 1    |  2    

3       | 0    |  0 

4       | 2    |  3

5       | 0    |  0
```

and requests table

```
request_id |  request | seat_no | person_id
-------------------------------------------
1          |  1       |  3      |  4   
2          |  2       |  2      |  5    
3          |  2       |  1      |  1
```

### Addming one more row to the requests table where we have more than one seat request for seat number three. In such case we will have to take the row with the minimum value of request id.
4 | 2 | 3 | 1

The desired output

```
seat_no | status | person_id
----------------------------
1       |  2     |  1    
2       |  1     |  2    
3       |  1     |  4    
4       |  2     |  3    
5       |  0     |  0
```

The first request is completed because seat number 3 is free. The second request is ignored because seat number 2 is already reserved by another person. The third request is completed because seat number 1 was reserved by this person, so they can purchase it.

My approach to reach to the solution was to outer join the two tables seats and requests and then using conditions to display the desired result but this query returns only the last two rows correctly:

```
  select seat_no,status,person_id from

(SELECT COALESCE(r.request_id,0) as request_id,s.seat_no, 
case when s.person_id=r.person_id then r.request 
 when s.person_id=0 then  COALESCE(r.request,s.status)
 else s.status 
end as status,

case when s.person_id=0 and r.person_id is not null then r.person_id 
    when s.person_id!=r.person_id then s.person_id
  else s.person_id
end as person_id
from seats s 
left outer join requests r on s.seat_no=r.seat_no ) t 
group by request_id,t.seat_no,status,person_id 
order by seat_no asc
```

Comment: Your query gives your desired result so what's the problem?

Comment: It is not giving the desired result. Matched 2 rows of the desired result only

Comment: Looks ok to me https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q34ogb1Sge5CjgiyawsnW7/0 what result do you get

Comment: I am only getting the last two rows correctly . rest if gettting different values forthe first three. Plus I doubt whether my approach is correct or not . And if there is a better and optimized way to achieve the solution.

Comment: If you aren’t getting the same result as the fiddle then you are not using the same code or the published data is not a representative sample. Please confirm the fiddle produces the desired result

Comment: @P.Salmon I am getting the same results now. But I am trying to find a better anwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.seat_no, 
  If(s.person_id = 0 || s.person_id = r.person_id, coalesce(r.request, s.status), coalesce(s.status, r.request)) as status, 
 If(s.person_id = 0 || s.person_id = r.person_id, coalesce(r.person_id, s.person_id), coalesce(s.person_id, r.person_id)) as person_id from 
seats s left join (SELECT a.*
FROM requests a
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT seat_no,
    MIN(request_id) as request_id
  FROM requests 
  GROUP BY seat_no
) AS b
  ON a.seat_no = b.seat_no
  AND a.request_id = b.request_id)
as r on s.seat_no = r.seat_no order by s.seat_no;
```